# (Swift 4)Use UIPanGestureRecognizer rotate a view but in wrong position

Tags: ios, rotation, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a container UIView and a button at right top of container, when I rotate button, I want to make container rotate by angle. But the code not work correctly 
 just rotate fastly.

```
   @objc func btnRotatePanAction(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        origin = sender.location(in: self)
        break
    case .changed:
        let second = sender.location(in: self)
        let dx = second.x - origin.x
        let dy = second.y - origin.y
        let radians = atan2(dy, dx); // get bearing in radians
        print("rads: \(radians)")
        container.transform = container.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(radians))
        origin = second
        break
    case .ended:
        break
    default: break

    }
}
```

Log output like this:

rads: 1.69022525281324

rads: 0.519146114246523

rads: 0.643501108793284

Answer (score 0):

Do you transform the same view, which you applied UIPanGestureRecognizer to? It seems that you after transform coordinate system is also changed according to this transform and it changes every time `btnRotatePanAction(_:)` called. That's why everythings turn around rapidly (and randomly I guess).

You can add a subview to view which handles UIPanGestureRecognizer and transform subview not main view.

And by the way, instead of saving origin position of tap you can just use `sender.translation(in: sender.view!)` which returns how touch is changed in coordinate system.